# Oracle PL / SQL Web toolkit on WLS 10.3

Tags: plsql, weblogic-10.x, oracle-apex

Anyone has any experience using application developed using Oracle PL / SQL Web toolkit and deploying it on WLS 10.3 ?

We have an old application created in Oracle PL / SQL Web toolkit which is currently hosted on OAS. The client wants us to migrate the application to Weblogic server (10.3). I wanted to know if anyone has heard of any plug-in or has any experience in doing this ?

Any pointers in this direction will be really helpful.

Thanks.
Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some digging around this is what i found:

There are two ways of getting this migration done without re-writing the code:

1. Install OHS(with mod PL/SQL) using Oracle SOA Suite 10g(10.1.3.3) and use .
2. Upgrade HTML DB from its existing version to Apex 3.2 or higher.

Oracle Documentation says there are 2 ways of doing it: In order to run, Oracle Application Express must have access to either the “embedded PL/SQL gateway” or “Oracle HTTP Server and mod_plsql”.

With Oracle 11g documentation website confirms that Oracle HTTP server is still compatible:
“Oracle HTTP Server: Starting with Oracle Database 11g, Oracle HTTP Server is available on a separate media shipped with Oracle Database. In the previous releases, this product was available as a Companion CD component.
Note: To install Oracle HTTP Server, use the Oracle Fusion Middleware Web Tier Utilities 11g (11.1.1.2.0) media or download.”

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32002/whatsnew.htm#sthref10

To set up OHS and mod_plsql this is the official guide (Downloading from OTN and Configuring Oracle HTTP Server)
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10513_01/doc/install.310/e10496/overview.htm#CHDCEJIE

[EDIT:] Let me add this, PL/SQL Web Toolkit & mod_plsql has NOTHING to do with Weblogic. The mod is designed to run on an Apache Instance. Oracle OHS is nothing but modified Apache 1.3. You can dare and try to install modplsql (Or its opensource version mod_owa) on vanilla Apache 2.2 instance but the risk is all yours...